# (Bootstrap) Having Issue with the Carousel Pictures

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, scale

The picture does not scale automatically if you zoom. I don't know how I can fix this.

[Home HTML](http://jsbin.com/runacejati/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Plz add your code also to the question.

Comment: I add CSS but I dont have more.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you use and background-images are not responsive by default

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image:url(images/slider/bg1.jpg)">
```

for your images, I suggest using

```
<div class="item active>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/slider/bg1.jpg">
</div>
```

img-responsive class will scale your image according to the window and carousel size.